# How to perform Amazon Cloud Search with .net code?

Tags: java, c#, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudsearch

I am learning Amazon Cloud Search but I couldn't find any code in either C# or Java (though I am creating in C# but if I can get code in Java then I can try converting in C#).

This is just 1 code I found in C#: https://github.com/Sitefinity-SDK/amazon-cloud-search-sample/tree/master/SitefinityWebApp.

This is 1 method i found in this code:

```
 public IResultSet Search(ISearchQuery query)
        {
            AmazonCloudSearchDomainConfig config = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainConfig();
            config.ServiceURL = "http://search-index2-cdduimbipgk3rpnfgny6posyzy.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/";
            AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient domainClient = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient("AKIAJ6MPIX37TLIXW7HQ", "DnrFrw9ZEr7g4Svh0rh6z+s3PxMaypl607eEUehQ", config);
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
            List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder highlights = new StringBuilder();
            highlights.Append("{\'");

            if (query == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("query");

            foreach (var field in query.HighlightedFields)
            {
                if (highlights.Length > 2)
                {
                    highlights.Append(", \'");
                }

                highlights.Append(field.ToUpperInvariant());
                highlights.Append("\':{} ");
                SuggestRequest suggestRequest = new SuggestRequest();
                Suggester suggester = new Suggester();
                suggester.SuggesterName = field.ToUpperInvariant() + "_suggester";
                suggestRequest.Suggester = suggester.SuggesterName;
                suggestRequest.Size = query.Take;
                suggestRequest.Query = query.Text;
                SuggestResponse suggestion = domainClient.Suggest(suggestRequest);
                foreach (var suggest in suggestion.Suggest.Suggestions)
                {
                    suggestions.Add(suggest.Suggestion);
                }
            }

            highlights.Append("}");

            if (query.Filter != null)
            {
                searchRequest.FilterQuery = this.BuildQueryFilter(query.Filter);
            }

            if (query.OrderBy != null)
            {
                searchRequest.Sort = string.Join(",", query.OrderBy);
            }

            if (query.Take > 0)
            {
                searchRequest.Size = query.Take;
            }

            if (query.Skip > 0)
            {
                searchRequest.Start = query.Skip;
            }

            searchRequest.Highlight = highlights.ToString();
            searchRequest.Query = query.Text;
            searchRequest.QueryParser = QueryParser.Simple;

            var result = domainClient.Search(searchRequest).SearchResult;

            //var result = domainClient.Search(searchRequest).SearchResult;

            return new AmazonResultSet(result, suggestions);
        }
```

I have already created domain in Amazon Cloud Search using AWS console and uploaded document using Amazon predefine configuration option that is **movie Imdb json** file provided by Amazon for demo.

But in this method I am not getting how to use this method, like if I want to search **Director** name then how do I pass in this method as because this method parameter is of type **ISearchQuery**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the official [AWS CloudSearch .NET SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-net/). The library you were looking at seems fine (although I haven't look at it any detail) but the official version is more likely to expose new CloudSearch features as soon as they're released, will be supported if you need to talk to AWS support, etc, etc.

Specifically, take a look at the [SearchRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudSearchDomain/TCloudSearchDomainSearchRequest.html) class -- all its params are strings so I think that obviates your question about ISearchQuery.

I wasn't able to find an example of a query in .NET but [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=578375) shows someone uploading docs using the AWS .NET SDK. It's essentially the same procedure as querying: creating and configuring a Request object and passing it to the client.

**EDIT**:
Since you're still having a hard time, here's an example. Bear in mind that I am unfamiliar with C# and have not attempted to run or even compile this but I think it should at least be close to working. It's based off looking at the docs at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/

```
// Configure the Client that you'll use to make search requests
string queryUrl = @"http://search-<domainname>-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com";
AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient searchClient = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient(queryUrl);

// Configure a search request with your query
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.Query = "potato";
// TODO Set your other params like parser, suggester, etc

// Submit your request via the client and get back a response containing search results
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchClient.Search(searchRequest);
```

Comment: thanks for replying but did you check the link which i have provided in my question?

Comment: I see, he's actually using the AWS SDK but it's a very old version. ISearchQuery isn't part of the latest API so if you use the latest, you'll be able to pass your query term as a string.

Comment: I have search alot regarding this ISearchQuery but its an interface only.you have any link?

Comment: There is no ISearchQuery in the latest AWS SDK. Use that and you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you.sir can you please elaborate on your last comment as i am badly stuck in this issue and there is not more help or code available on google so.The function i have provided in my code i am struggling in that like how do i create SearchRequest,SuggestRequest,Suggester  etc..i would be so glad if you could help me on my Search function provided in question

Comment: Added an example (see caveat that I don't know C# and haven't tested it). Hope it helps. Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much.In your profile you have written you answer only cloud search related question.so have u worked on all aws services as because i have seen your ans only on major aws related question

Comment: I interact with AWS fairly often although it's often heavily abstracted by in-house tools and libraries. I've never been employed by Amazon, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No i am not asking that you have been employed by aws.actually i am learning aws small components like aws sns service,cloud search and now i have just started with aws Elastic beanstalk.have you ever used it?