# How to create aws elastic beanstalk worker tier in .Net with step by step guide?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am learning various components of Aws amazon Web services in which currently i am learning Elastic beanstalk.

So far i have been able to deploy sample application provided on demo page by aws only(docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/aws-elastic-beanstalk-dotnet-sample-application.zip).

> But now i want to understand and create any simple demo on worker role
>   so that i can use worker role in my any live application.

This is some of the usefull resource i have found for worker role:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/background-task-handling-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuwfVX52PV8

But all this are in python or other language.

I have even search alot on **aws forum website** but i have seen unanswered question on WorkerTier in .Net:

[Worker Tier in .Net](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=620009&#620009)

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=617716&#617716

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=522778&#522778

So can anybody provide me any good reference or step by step guide of how to **create worker role in .Net with code** or from management console and perform any simple task for demo so that i can understand worker role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS .NET workers are not supported (only explanation is that Queue Demon is writen in language that is only hostable on Linux).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html

> Worker environments are supported for all platforms except .NET.

So you can create "worker like" application but host it as normal webapplication. But you would need to create your own .NET queue demon, handle security (i have read that worker web service is not callable outside of localhost), autoscale etc.

Comment: like in azure we can have worker so same thing is not there in aws?

Comment: Not sure how it is done in azure. Here "out of the box" workers are limited to Linux platform and following languages "Docker, Go (Golang), Java,  Node.js, PHP, Python, and Ruby". As I mentioned you can try to overcome this difficulty by creating normal WWW application (or simple EC2 instance) but you have to handle a lot by yourself.

Comment: Have u done any  backgroud task with aws worker in .net?

Comment: Each solution which uses .net is twisted hack and using AWS as it was not designed. Our soultion is simple Java webservice which forwards call to .NET worker. .NET Worker is normal Elastibeanstalk WWW application which you already used

Comment: Have you ever used aws cloud search?

Comment: Hi. Please mark my anwser (or not) and create other question about cloud search.

Comment: Take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219777/how-to-perform-amazon-cloud-search-with-net-code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try do it your own, if you don't find any good sources, because it's fairly simple. (And it's similar if you using .net or python)

A background worker is just a web server. AWS is nice and does lots of the work for you. What you need to have is an application that replies for simple HTTP Post calls. During the post call, you will get the JSON content from the SQS and you handle it how you wish.

If you open the first link and download the "Sample application source bundle", check the "application.py". Even if you don't know python, you will see it's just 1 simple endpoint. Don't forget to give a valid reply (HTTP OK(200) if your worker finished well, or 500 if there is an error.)

The deployment should be the same like deploying the front end to Beanstalk. (Use Visual Studio with the AWS plugin, it has Beanstalk deployment capabilities.)

Comment: I was expecting some kind of code with some proper steps so that i can perform it and i have notice that there is lots of scarcity on internet for aws components for .Net and proper help is not available too on aws forum too and on stackoverflow.so feeling helpless right now for worker tier.anyways thank you so much for this answer but honestly speaking i didnt get anything from your answer and i have upvoted because of your kind efforts for writing this answer for me from your busy schedule.So once again thank you so much.